# MVVM Light (Win10) IDialogService.ShowMessage with .Wait() doesn't carry on execution

Tags: uwp, windows-10, mvvm-light

I am writing a UWP application (mainly targeting Windows Mobile 10) using the MVVM Light project template.  I require a check on startup that determines the device ID, and I am trying to exit the application if it fails to find the ID.

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    try
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("ug");
        //DeviceId = Utilities.GetDeviceId();
    }
    catch
    {
        IDialogService noIDWarningDialog = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDialogService>();
        noIDWarningDialog.ShowMessage("Unable to determine device ID.\nShutting down application.\nPlease contact IT.", "Error").Wait();

        ShutdownService.RequestShutdown();
    }
}
```

When runnign on the x86 Emulator (10.0.1.14393.0), the line `noIDWarningDialog.ShowMessage(...).Wait()` successfully shows a dialog box, but when the `OK` button is pressed, the next line is not run.  The app sits on the splash screen and a breakpoint on `ShutdownService.RequestShutdown()` is not hit.

What have I got wrong?

Comment: never ever use .Wait(), but use await on async methods.

Comment: e.g. you could outsource the body of this MainViewModel() into an async method and instead of doing  noIDWarningDialog.ShowMessage("...").Wait(); do 

await  noIDWarningDialog.ShowMessage("..", "Error"); in the async mehtod.

Comment: Or you can leave it there and do: noIDWarningDialog.ShowMessage("...").ContinueWith((t) => { Application.Current.Exit(); });